# std::initializer_list constructor leading to compiler errors C3202, C2661 and C2976

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, stdinitializerlist

I'm using a graphics library included in a C++ textbook, which has the following definition for a shape that is supposed to create objects comprised of straight lines.

```
 struct Lines : Shape {  // independent lines
    Lines() {}
    Lines(initializer_list<Point> lst)
        : Shape{ lst }
    {
        if (lst.size() % 2)
            error("odd number of points for Lines");
    }
    Lines(initializer_list<pair<Point>> lst)
    {
        for (auto p : lst) add(p.first, p.second);
    }
    void draw_lines() const;
    void add(Point p1, Point p2) { Shape::add(p1); Shape::add(p2); }
}
```

However when I try to create an instance of the Lines struct, like this:

```
Lines rec(Point{ 200,200 }, Point{ 100,100 }, Point{350,250});
```

I get the error C2976, C2228 and C3202, stating:

> C2976 - "std::pair': too few template arguments"
>
> C2228 - "pair': unspecialized class template can't be used as a
>   template 
>            argument for template parameter '_Elem', expected a real type"
>
> C2661 - "Graph_lib::Lines::Lines': no overloaded function takes 3
>   arguments"

I was under the impression that the initializer_list constructor allows initializing an object with multiple elements of the same type as the parameters.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Note that you aren't creating an initialiser list in your code sample

Answer (score 0):

First for `std::pair` you should specify two types: `std::pair<Point, Point>`.

Second you should pass `std::initializer_list` as the single argument:

`Lines rec({ Point{ 200,200 }, Point{ 100,100 }, Point{350,250} });`

Comment: Doing so results in Linker errors. Namely: LNK2019 and LNK1120.

Comment: It's another type of error. Сompilation phase successfully completed. Error code is not enough.